# How to obtain the url from getDownloadURL()

Tags: firebase, vue.js, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I have tried every avenue that i can seem to find, i have found lots of solutions but none that seem to be right for my application!

i have gotten to a point where i successfully upload a photo to firebase along with all of the other information however when i try retrieve the URL for the file that has been uploaded it keeps saying

> Reference.child failed: First argument was an invalid path = "undefined". Paths must be non-empty strings and can't contain ".", "#", "$", "[", or "]"

however i can see that the url is inside of a list

```
{a: 0, i: undefined, c: A, b: null, f: null, …}
a: 2
b: null
c: null
f: null
g: false
h: false
i: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/hikershangout.appspot.com/o/hangouts%2F-LUDFPpNTBdAdmUu_gLW..jpg?alt=media&token=cffdd574-1b9d-426e-a078-8d18ca5bdf7f"
__proto__: Object
```

So now how to obtain this url?

```js
.then (key => {
  const filename = payload.image.name
  const ext = filename.slice(filename.lastIndexOf('.'))
  return firebase.storage().ref('hangouts/' + key + '.' + ext).put(payload.image)
})
.then(fileData => {
  imageUrl = fileData.ref.getDownloadURL()
  console.log(imageUrl)
  return firebase.database().ref('hangouts').child(key).update({imageUrl: imageUrl})
})
.then(() => {
  commit('createHangout', {
    ...hangout,
    imageUrl: imageUrl,
    id: key
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since about half a year ago `getDownloadUrl()` doesn't immediately return the download URL anymore, but returns a promise that resolves with the download URL.

Phil is also correct that neither `key` nor `imageUrl` will be defined in your final `then()`.

So combined you might need:

```
var key, imageUrl;

...
.then (key => {
  const filename = payload.image.name
  const ext = filename.slice(filename.lastIndexOf('.'))
  this.key = key;
  return firebase.storage().ref('hangouts/' + key + '.' + ext).put(payload.image)
})
.then(fileData => {
  return fileData.ref.getDownloadURL()
}).then((imageUrl) => {
  console.log(imageUrl)
  this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
  return firebase.database().ref('hangouts').child(key).update({imageUrl: imageUrl})
})
.then(() => {
  commit('createHangout', {
    ...hangout,
    imageUrl: imageUrl,
    id: key
  })
})
```

Comment: thanks for your help! however im still really struggling to get this to work! here is my github repo and the live site on firebase... any chance you could take a look and see what im doing wrong???

https://github.com/dothecoolwip/help2     
https://hikersmeetup.firebaseapp.com

Comment: turns out im actually not able to get the KEY from the code... and i so lost on how to get it please help. lol

Comment: Sorry, there's way to much code in a repo for us to efficiently help, which is why Stack Overflow works best when you create a [minimal, complete, self-contained example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For example: the code in your question doesn't show what happens before the first `then`, so we have no way to know what key is meant to be, nor where it's supposed to come from.

Answer (score 1):

In your second `then()`, `key` is not defined but you're trying to use it in `child(key)`.

I would recommend combining the first two `then()` blocks so everything you need is available. For example

```js
.then (key => {
  const filename = payload.image.name
  const ext = filename.slice(filename.lastIndexOf('.'))
  return firebase.storage().ref('hangouts/' + key + '.' + ext).put(payload.image).then(fileData => {
    const imageUrl = fileData.ref.getDownloadURL()
    console.log(imageUrl)
    return firebase.database().ref('hangouts').child(key).update({ imageUrl })
  })
}).then(() => {
  commit(...)
  // etc
})
```

Comment: thanks for your help! however im still really struggling to get this to work! here is my github repo and the live site on firebase... any chance you could take a look and see what im doing wrong???

https://github.com/dothecoolwip/help2     
https://hikersmeetup.firebaseapp.com